# $H(H(x)) = H(x)$ for all $x$

Tags: calculus, functions

In Spivak's Calculus book I've been asked to find a function $H(x)$ such that $H(H(x)) = H(x)$ for all $x$, and $H(x)$ must satisfy: $$H(1)=36,\   \ H(2) = \pi/3,\   \ H(13) = 47$$

The $\pi/3$ suggests trig., which is quite pathetic progress on my part, but I'm not really sure how one would go about generating a function of this type

Comment: What page is this from?

Comment: Definitely don't need trig function. Must $H$ be continuous?

Comment: Hints: H(1)=36. Thus H(H(1))=36=H(36). H(2)=pi/3. Thus H(H(2))=H(pi/3)=pi/3. H(13)=47. Thus H(H(13))=H(47)=47.

Comment: This question is from page 50-51

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the condition $H(H(x)) = H(x)$ is satisfied by constant functions. Use this observation to cook up a piecewise constant function which satisfies the other given conditions.

Edited to give further hints:

Specifically, you know that $H(H(1)) = H(1)$, and so this tells you $H(36) = 36$. Similarly, $H(\pi/3) = \pi/3$ and $H(47) = 47$. So, now you can plot six points on the graph of this function. If you want to extend this to a function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, fill in the gaps with appropriate constant functions.

Comment: Hmm, $H^2=H$ holds for constant functions, but it's not clear how to keep a handle on the piecewise ones. If $f$ is the characteristic function of $[0,1]$, then even $2f$ is not idempotent. It would be nice if you could expand on your idea about what else would go into cooking :)

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören He doesn't claim that $H(H(x))=H(x) \iff H(x) \equiv C$.

Answer (score 1):

What about $H(x)=x$ if $x\notin \{{1,2,13}\}$, together with the given constraints?

Comment: I noticed that initially, but doesn't restricting the domain mean that the conditions $H(2) = pi/3$ etc aren't satisfied? EDIT: Or I just state $H(2) = pi/3$ etc?

Comment: @user121591 yes, you can define $f$ by explicitly saying $f(2)=\pi /3$ etc., $f(x)=x$ otherwise.